# Loop and sort result without duplication

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

Can you suggest me what will be the good way to convert result without duplication?

```
$numbers = array ('1', '5', '10');
 foreach ($numbers as $number){
  $query[] = $this->db->query("SELECT name, country FROM name WHERE id= '" . (int)$number .'"")
 }
```

Result

```
 Array (
  Array (
   name = ivan
   country = en
  )
  Array(
   name = Peter
   country = en
  )
  Array (
   name = sisi's
   country = en
  )
 )
```

How can I sort result like this

```
  Array(
   country = en
   name = array (
     sisi's
     Peter
     Ivan
   )
 )
```

Comment: The result does not seem right. There's clearly a column called `id` in your table `name`, yet when you select all the columns `id` doesn't show up in the result. Are you saying there are duplicates in the database? What if there are multiple countries in the database?

Comment: Reformat your array in php loop.

Comment: @KIKO Software yes it's a Id also I rework the code ,  if are multiple countries will be nice to be sorted in array with their names but no idea how to do it

Comment: @u_mulder what you mean ? Can you show any examples?

Comment: Examples how to work with arrays can be found in internet.

Comment: You could do this with SQL itself and then use an explode in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your query.

```php
$numbers = array ('1', '5', '10');

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT country,
GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS name
FROM name 
WHERE id IN(".implode(',',$numbers).")
GROUP BY country";

$this->db->query($sql);
```

Than after getting the result, you can convert the string names into array with explode function.

Comment: You are star it's look so easy :) I will try it later